# flutter web showing "flutter" on the holding browser back button for long in safari

Tags: flutter, dart, dom, flutter-web

In other broswer its working fine but in safari its showing "flutter" on the holding browser back button for long!  
[image: In Safari] 
[image: In Chrome]

I want to show the name of the application or the url which gets loaded